# WPF Popup not auto-sizing properly

Tags: wpf, popup, height

I have a Popup that should show errors. This Popup present a TextBlock which is binded to a field ErrorMessage. The binding apparently works properly since my Error message update properly. However when the message is too long, the Height of the Popup doesn't change and some part of the error message remain hidden. I was sure that the WPF Popup automatically adapted its size to its content however in this situation I can't seem to make it work.

The error message is declared as follows :

```
private String _errorMessage;
public String ErrorMessage
{
    get { return _errorMessage; }
    set
    {
        _errorMessage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Its value is changed in the function `FindErrorInDates()`:

```
public void FindErrorInDates()
{
    this.ErrorCount = 0;
    this.HasError = false;
    List<String> errors = new List<String>();
    if (this.OutwardDeparturePlannedDate >= this.OutwardArrivalPlannedDate)
    {
       this.ErrorCount += 1;
       errors.Add("Outward : Departure must be before Arrival");
    }

    if (this.ReturnDeparturePlannedDate >= this.ReturnArrivalPlannedDate)
    {
        this.ErrorCount += 1;
        errors.Add("Return : Departure must be before Arrival");
    }

    if (this.OutwardDeparturePlannedDate >= this.ReturnDeparturePlannedDate
                || this.OutwardDeparturePlannedDate >= this.ReturnArrivalPlannedDate
                || this.OutwardArrivalPlannedDate >= this.ReturnDeparturePlannedDate
                || this.OutwardArrivalPlannedDate >= this.ReturnArrivalPlannedDate)
    {
        this.ErrorCount += 1;
        errors.Add("Conflict between Outward Date and Return Date");
    }

    this.HasError = this.ErrorCount > 0;
    this.ErrorMessage = String.Join("\r\n", errors);
}
```

and finally the Popup. I've tried every mix of attributes `Height` and `Width`. I can't seem to figure out how to make this ErrorMessage properly fit into a Popup of 200 Width. What am I missing ?

```
<Popup Height="Auto"  IsOpen="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=ValidDepartureDate, Mode=OneWay}" PopupAnimation="None" Placement="Bottom" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Border Height="Auto" Width="200" CornerRadius="2" Padding="5" Background="DarkRed" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.List.Presenter.JourneyResUtility.ErrorCount, Converter={StaticResource ZeroToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <TextBlock Height="Auto"  Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource SmallFontStyle}" Text="{Binding DataContext.List.Presenter.JourneyResUtility.ErrorMessage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Comment: were you able to fix this at that time

Comment: Hi WizLiz. Were you able to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
Height="*"
```

AND

```
Width="*"
```

Or is the problem the textbox which doesn't seem to adapt to its content?

Comment: Well I've thought about the value `"*"` however this doesnt seem to work either. The popup doesnt even show up when I try `Height="*"`. I can't tell if its the textbox that doesnt change size or the Popup itself (or the border that cause the issue).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Height = "auto"
 Width = "auto"
```